# How do I tell if a transition/transform is 3d accelerated in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css, 3d, hardware-acceleration

In Chrome you have the debug flag: `--show-composited-layer-borders`. Is there an equivalent in Firefox? Googling hasn't yielded much.